# Процентное соотношение одних чисел применить к другим

Tags: c#, математика

Последние пару часов сижу с калькулятором в зубах и не понимаю, как должна выглядеть формула.

Как правильно выразить задачу с математической точки зрения - я не знаю, поэтому, объясню как ученик 3Б класса:

Мы получаем значение от -много до +много. Если значение <250, то возвращаем 2. Если значение >380, то возращаем 8. А если значение 250< X <380, то нужно вернуть ~что-то между 2 и 8~, например, если X=260, то вернём ~2.3, если X=300, то вернём ~4.9, если X=360, то вернём ~7.6.

Накидал минимальный пример:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    for (int i = 240; i < 390; ++i)
        Foo(i);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Foo(int num) {
    const int minPoint = 250;
    const int maxPoint = 380;
    const double change = 2;
    const double change2 = 8;

    double result;
    if (num < minPoint)
        result = change;
    else if (num > maxPoint)
        result = change2;
    else
        result = ??;

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Надеюсь, что вопрос понятен.

Comment: Как распределяются значения? Равномерно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = (num - minPoint)*(change2 - change)/(maxPoint-minPoint) + change;
```